# Cannot Resolve Symbol 'Ads'

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I'm using Android Studio and trying to setup admob in my app. I've followed the instructions from Google for setup of admob (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start#introduction) and have read through these instructions a number of times trying to find the cause. I have also installed, removed and reinstalled the required packages in SDK manager to no avail.

I cannot import these packages:
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

...and get the error 'Cannot Resolve Symbol 'Ads'' when I try to do so.
I have tried 'Invalide Caches/Restart' several times too.

Here is some of the key info from build.gradle which may help finding an answer:

```
minSdkVersion 9
targetSdkVersion 9
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
```

I have added the dependancy:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
```

One thing I forgot to mention in my original post, is that my project has a library module, then under that another library module, then under that my two app modules.

Thanks in advance all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a long time trying to fix this and now I've managed to sort it and get rid of the errors.

I went through a number of steps, some of which I already tried in various orders, but I've attempted to list below all the steps I took in the time the error disappeared:

- Ran 'build->clean', synced and ran 'invalidate caches/restart'

  - Removed all  references to Google play repositories from my gradle files for apps in my structure, then add the reference again but only in the gradle for the top level library module (I previously had it in all four).
- Removed the project from my dropbox folder to another location on my C drive (I'm hoping this wasn't part of the problem).
- Closed the project, open Android Studio then IMPORT the project again from its new location.

Like I say, I'm not sure which of the steps fixed the problem, but it is now sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Click on Build > Clean Project